# What is a `##` means in bash variable substitution `${}`?

Tags: bash

I am learning the bash script materials on http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html
and stuck in the Example 7-7:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html#EX14

There is an `${filename##*.} != "gz"`, this probably means
that the `$filename` does not end with `.gz`, but I do not 
know the meaning of `##` here. Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: From your shell, you can also run `man bash`, then hit the forward slash to start a search, type `##` and hit Enter. Magic!  :-D  (And that entire section, "Parameter Expansion" is worth a close look.)

Comment: That is holy great! @ghoti

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Used in a variable expansion, `${string##sub}` removes the longest matching substring `sub` from `string` (`#` removes the shortest matching substring by contrast).

In your case, yes - this will return the string after the first `.` from the filename, giving the file extension.

If you search for `##` in [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) documentation, you'll find an explanation (along with other similar commands).

Comment: Thanks. WIth your help, I found the guide of expansion on http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22728 .

Comment: @cmal I hadn't seen the refcards page before - that's actually really, really useful, bookmarking that. Thanks for showing me something new!

Answer (score 1):

In the context of filenames, is trying to find the extension in the variable filename

```
filename="*.log"
echo ${filename##*.}
log
```

We are attaining the part of the string filename after "*."

Answer (score 1):

`##` is a used for to remove a substring from a variable. For more info check [this](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) page.

For eg. if `filename=/home/user.name/folder.1/test.gz`, then ${filename##*.} will give you output as `gz`.